# MIPS using arrays with any number problem

Tags: arrays, mips, offset

```
  .data
  .align 2
Z:  .word  6, 7, 8 ,9 , 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36
k:  .word  0            
m:  .word  0            

  .text
  .globl main
main:                   # main is global label
  addu  $s7, $0, $ra    # save return address
  lw  $s1, Z            # base address of Z in $s1

#------------------------------------getting k
  .data
  .globl  message1  
message1:  .asciiz "\nInput value for k: "  #string to print

  .text
  li  $v0, 4            # print_string (system call 4)
  la  $a0, message1     # takes the address of string as an argument 
  syscall
  li  $v0, 5            # read_int (system call 5) 
  syscall
  add  $t1, $0, $v0     # -> $s2
  sw  $t1, k            # k is stored
#------------------------------------getting m
  .data
  .globl  message2
message2:  .asciiz "\nInput value for m: "    #string to print

  .text
  li  $v0, 4            # print_str (system call 4)
  la  $a0, message2     # takes the address of string as an argument 
  syscall
  li  $v0, 5            # read_int (system call 5)
  syscall
  add  $s3, $0, $v0     # -> $s3
  sw  $s3, m            # m is stored


#-----------------------------------calculating Z[12] = Z[k] + Z[k+m]
  .text
  lw $t0, k($s1)        # store Z[k] -> $t0
  add $t1, $s2, $s3     # k + m -> $t1
  lw $t2, m($s1)        # store Z[k+m] -> $t2
  add $t3, $t0, $t2     # Z[k] + Z[k+m] -> $t3
  sw $t3, 48($s1)       # store Z[k] + Z[k+m] -> Z[12]
```

I cant seem to understand why the calculating Z[12] = Z[k] + Z[k+m] part of the code is a complete failure and just results in errors. Ive tried looking over my notes and read the manual, but no luck. im missing something important...

im guessing that it has something do with the offset calculation?? as 
lw $t0, k($s1)
lw $t2, m($s1)
sw $t3, 48($s1)

all give errors to me. which means they are completely wrong and basically wrong syntax. but i dont know what to do other than this.

Answer (score 0):

If you look up `lw` and `sw` in a MIPS instruction set reference, it should become apparent that there's no form of those instructions that matches e.g. `lw $t0, k($s1)`.

Some assemblers my actually accept those as *pseudo-instructions* (the assembler will convert them into two or more actual instructions), but with a different meaning than the one you're hoping for: e.g. `lw $t0, k($s1)` would have the meaning `$t0 = k[$s1]`, *not* `$t0 = $s1[k]`.

You need to do something like this:

```
lw $t0, k
sll $t0, $t0, 2     # t0 = k * sizeof(word)
addu $t0, $t0, $s1  # t0 += &Z
lw $t1, ($t0)
```

---

Note that `sw $t3, 48($s1)` is perfectly valid, so it's unclear what you mean when you say that it's giving you an error.

Comment: your last line of code 'lw $t1, ($t0)' doesnt seem to be a legal instruction either- it just returns an error.

Comment: It's a perfectly valid instruction. What is the exact error message? You haven't made clear which assembler you're using.